# How to management certificate for 1 app but have many bundle id?

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store, ipa, firebase-app-distribution

Hi I'm new for iOS development, I created my application and I separate bundle id for 3 ids for each environment ( dev, staging, production )

example.

```
com.xxx.bb.dev
com.xxx.bb.staging
com.xxx.bb
```

**For my requirement now,**

1. I have to link my app to firebase distribution for deliver my app to tester for all 3 environments.
2. I have to separate p12 cert for push notification for each environment.
3. `dev and staging` is use for tester only and `prod` use for upload to testflight and store

**My question is.**

In apple developer program, I have to create 3 app ids for each environments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can not have one app ID for 3 bundles. You would need to create 3 separate apps ids for each environment.